# NoClassDefFoundError when compiling Spring project in terminal

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to learn Spring, and I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-tutorial.

Here's what I've done:

I've created a directory `springtutorial` and put these two files in it:

**`Student.java`**

```
package com.javatpoint; 

public class Student{
        private String name;

        public String getName(){
                return name;
        }

        public void displayInfo(){
                System.out.println("Hello:" + name);
        }
}
```

**`Test.java`:**

```
package com.javatpoint;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
                BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);

                Student student = (Student) factory.getBean("studentbean");
                student.displayInfo();
        }
}
```

Also, I've created an XML file **`applicationContext.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

        <bean id="studentbean" class="com.javatpoint.Student">
                <propertyname="name" value="Vimal Jaiswal"></property>
        </bean>
</beans>
```

Lastly, I've downloaded these Spring core files: https://www.javatpoint.com/src/sp/spcorejars.zip

I've put everything except the .jar files in the same folder. The .jar files are placed in a sub-folder:

```
~/springtutorial$ ls
applicationContext.xml  spcorejars  Student.java  Test.java
~/springtutorial$ ls spcorejars/
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar  org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar           org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
jmxtools-1.2.1.jar                                     org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar            org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
```

Compiling **`Student.java`** works fine:

```
~/springtutorial$ javac -d . Student.java
```

and after som tinkering I managed to compile **`Test.java`** (.jar files in separate sub-folder):

```
~/springtutorial$ javac -cp ".:spcorejars/*" -d . Test.java
```

But I can't run the test file:

```
~/springtutorial$ java com.javatpoint.Test 
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.javatpoint.Test
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/Resource
```

By looking online, it seems to me like I should have all the .jar files I need. So what could be the cause of this error?

And before you ask: No, I don't want to use Maven or Gradle for doing this. The purpose of doing this is to see how everything **actually** works without any program doing it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the command :

```
~/springtutorial$ java -cp ".:spcorejars/*" com.javatpoint.Test
```